# LDAP - Grant user write permission to group / organizationalUnit

Tags: ldap, openldap, access-control-list

I tried to grant `cn=admin,ou=Administrators,dc=example,dc=com` full write access to `ou=People,dc=example,dc=com` so that this admin can create (and of course read) new entries under `ou=People` and also can modify them (e.g. changing passwords).

My ldif file looks like

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {4}to dn.subtree="ou=People,dc=example,dc=com" by dn.exact="cn=admin,ou=Administrators,dc=example,dc=com" write
```

After running it with
`ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f permission.ldif`, I just got

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
```

Anyone can explain what is wrong here and how to do it correct? Tried quite a lot things which I found online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few more trial and errors I found a working solution.

Take a look at this ldif:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAccess
-
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword by self write by dn="cn=admin,ou=Administrators,dc=example,dc=com" write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by * read
olcAccess: {2}to dn.subtree="ou=People,dc=example,dc=com" by dn.exact="ccn=admin,ou=Administrators,dc=example,dc=com" write
olcAccess: {3}to * by * read
```

/edit: Well, this lets you create new users under ou=People but you cannot change all attributes of them.

Comment: Is there any explanation for why the attribute cannot just be added, but has to be wiped and rewritten? Is it the order that matters? Thx